# Tri-nary processor?

Tags: computer-science

Every now and then, I run across a rumor of the Soviets building a tri-nary processor, way back when.  But I can never find a source beyond the infamous guy who knows a guy...

The idea is interesting, but I suspect it's mostly fantasy.

Has anyone ever heard of this from a *credible* source?  Or is this the Maths/Science/Engineering version of the majestic yeti?

Comment: Can we assume that you've read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer?

Comment: You are free to assume anything you like, but in this specific case you would have assumed incorrectly.  I don't know why "Ternary" never occurred to Me as a search term, but I'm glad you pointed it out.  Thanks a lot.